# Excel- How do I Find and Replace using the values from adjacent columns

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

I'm a complete newbie to excel so apologies for my lack of knowledge!

I have a spreadsheet with 3 columnns.

Column 1 has cells with a range of values that can be repeated several times ie A B C A A D.

Column 2 has a list of the unique values in column 1 ie A B C D.

Column 3 contains the values that I would like to updated Column 1 with ie a b c d.

What I need to do is search Column 1 using Column 2 as an array of values when a match is found replace it with the adjacent value in column 3. Ie find all the A's in Column 1 and replace with a.

I did start writing a very long if statement if value = A replace with a etc but I have hundreds of unique values so I'm sure this isn't the most verbose way

**Thanks in advance for your help**

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of VLOOKUP

Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup ( lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup] )